# Moldy apple core in potted plant

Tags: houseplants, compost, mold

Put an apple core in the pot with my plant and now it’s getting moldy and the mold is spreading to the soil. Will the mold hurt my plant? Or is this all part of the composting process?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Composting takes place where there is decomposition, high heat and pressure.  Typical compost bins are up three cubic feet.  Commercial composting often uses piles ten or twenty feet high.  Both are regularly turned over.

The apple core will not compost, just dry out.  The mold is unsightly but unlikely to harm your plant.

A green bin or other recycling program would be a better destination for your household organic waste.